# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm quite new to php, I cannot seem to find my error. I am trying to get a regestration form to work, this is a begining of project I am doing so far, i hope anyone could help. Thanks

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=PoetsIN;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)

include('/classes/DB.php');

if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];


DB::query(INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username,:password,:email)', array(':username=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email));
```

echo "Success!"; 
}
?>

Comment: `;` lost in the third line.

Comment: are u missing semicolon at the end of : $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)